Shadow catcher only works in viewport, in render it is invisible (no shadows caught)
I am able to get my shadow to show in the viewport render, but I can't get it to show in the final render. I only want to render the shadow (not the rat casting it).
You can see here that she shadow is caught in the viewport,

But in the final render, it isn't.

The Blend file on Dropbox, too large for Blend-Exchange

The file seems to be a bit of a mess, but you're right, the shadow should be showing up in render afaik, but it isn't. Maybe you should report as a bug? I'll look into it.

Is this what you want :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-71b0vPCFoZI1kMt2nvGvPPrFwLtqHhb/view?usp=drive_link ?

Hi, Douglas, if you're not having any luck, a stripped-down, minimal representative file, still manifesting the problem, may help, here.
